# Adding text , image to asp.net chart control

Tags: asp.net, data-visualization, mschart, linechart

I am using asp.net chart control to display chart on my website , below is the snippet of it:
[image: line chart]

The issue is i want to add the text and an arrow line on each point , so for instance on the point (60,october) I want to write text at this point: projection was highest and an arrow image.
Is it possible to acheive something like this, any suggestion or assistance will be highly appreciated, below is the code i have used to generate this chart:

```
double[] yValues = { 15, 60, 12, 13 };
        string[] xValues = { "September", "October", "November", "December" };


        chart.Width = 500;
        chart.Height = 200;
        chart.BorderSkin.SkinStyle = BorderSkinStyle.FrameThin1;

        ChartArea ca = new ChartArea();
        ca.Name = "Default";
        ca.AxisX.LineColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FEFEFE");
        ca.AxisX.LineWidth = 3;
        ca.AxisX.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dash;
        ca.AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
        ca.AxisX.MajorTickMark.LineWidth = 2;
        ca.AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "L";

        ca.AxisY.LineColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FEFEFE");
        ca.AxisY.LineWidth = 3;
        ca.AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = true;
        ca.AxisY.MajorTickMark.LineWidth = 2;
        ca.AxisY.Title = "yaxis";

        chart.ChartAreas.Add(ca);

        Legend legend = new Legend();
        chart.Legends.Add(legend);
        Series series = new Series("Series1");
        series.IsValueShownAsLabel = false;
        series.MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Circle;
        series.BorderWidth = 5;
        series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;

        series.ShadowOffset = 2;
        series.XValueType = ChartValueType.String;
        series.YValueType = ChartValueType.Double;
        series.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Trebuchet MS", 8);
        series.BorderColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#33CCFF");
        series.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#33CCFF");

        chart.Series.Add(series);
        chart.Series["Series1"].Points.DataBindXY(xValues, yValues);
        chart.DataManipulator.InsertEmptyPoints(1, System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.IntervalType.Days, "Series1");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to search for the largest data point and use property

```
datapoint.Label = "projection was highest";
```

Also easiest way to highlight the point is to use `datapoint.MarkerStyle` property. You can draw an arrow but I dont think its worth the hassle.